# C: Incompatible type on dynamic array of pointers of structure

Tags: c, pointers, malloc, dynamic-arrays

I need help to declare a dynamic array of pointers.
A read some articles and similar questions about it and I try to do it for my project but still frozen.

What I'm trying to do:

```
typedef struct recArmario Armario, *pArmario;

struct recArmario {
    int ID;
    pArmario next;
    pArmario prev;
    pCorredor parent;
};

pArmario auxArmarioTest1 = malloc(sizeof(Armario));
auxArmarioTest1->ID = 1;
pArmario auxArmarioTest2 = malloc(sizeof(Armario));
auxArmarioTest2->ID = 2;

(…)

//Dynamic array of pointer Armario:
pArmario arrArmariosPointers = malloc(sizeof(pArmario) * maxCorredores);
//Here is my doubt
*(arrArmariosPointers + idCorredor) = auxArmarioTest1;
```

Xcode is saying:

```
Assigning to 'struct recArmario' from incompatible type 'pArmario' (aka 'struct recArmario *'); dereference with *
```

I don't understand, "Assigning to 'struct recArmario'"?!
I declare one array of pArmario, I think so.

`*(arrArmariosPointers + idCorredor)` is equivalent to `arrArmariosPointers[idCorredor]`, right?

**UPDATE 1**:

*Thanks for the answers!*
I update my sample and still have problems.

```
pArmario auxArmarioTest1 = malloc(sizeof(Armario));
auxArmarioTest1->ID = 1;
pArmario auxArmarioTest2 = malloc(sizeof(Armario));
auxArmarioTest2->ID = 2;

//Dynamic array of pointer Armario:
pArmario arrArmariosPointers = malloc(sizeof(pArmario) * 5);
//Test
pArmario auxA;
auxA = arrArmariosPointers + 0; //I know, it's useless :)
auxA = auxArmarioTest1;
auxA = arrArmariosPointers + 1;
auxA = auxArmarioTest2;

printf("\nA%d",(arrArmariosPointers+0)->ID);
printf("\nA%d",(arrArmariosPointers+1)->ID);

free(auxArmarioTest1);
free(auxArmarioTest2);
```

The result I get is:

```
A0
A0
```

What I'm doing wrong, again?

**UPDATE 2**:

Forget my update 1, it was dumb. I'm just changing `auxA`.

**SOLUTION**:

```
pArmario* arrArmariosPointers = malloc(sizeof(pArmario) * 5);

arrArmariosPointers[0] = auxArmarioTest1;
arrArmariosPointers[1] = auxArmarioTest2;

printf("\nA%d",arrArmariosPointers[0]->ID);
printf("\nA%d",arrArmariosPointers[1]->ID);
```

Thanks everyone.

Comment: I hope you realize you're still not creating the dynamic array properly. A dynamic array with elements of type `pArmario` should be of type `pArmario*`, so that you get `pArmario` elements when you index it like this: `pArmario[0]`. Your way of indexing the array would look weird to anyone reading your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*(arrArmariosPointers + idCorredor) = auxArmarioTest1;
```

here `arrArmariosPointers + idCorredor` is a `pArmario` or `struct recArmario *`, dereferencing it give you a `struct recArmario` which you then assign to `auxArmarioTest1` which is a `struct recArmario *`. In short, you are assigning a pointer to a struct, thus the error

for your update 1, this may be what you are trying to achieve?

```
pArmario * arrArmariosPointers = malloc(sizeof(pArmario) * 5);
arrArmariosPointers[0] = auxArmarioTest1;
arrArmariosPointers[1] = auxArmarioTest2;

printf("\nA%d",(arrArmariosPointers[0])->ID);
printf("\nA%d",(arrArmariosPointers[1])->ID);
```

Comment: Doesn't work because *(arrArmariosPointers + 1) is equivalent to arrArmariosPointers[1] and (arrArmariosPointers + 1) = auxArmarioTest1 doesn't work neither.

Comment: No. `(arrArmariosPointers + 1)` is a `pArmario **` not `pArmario *`. tried the code, it prints `A1` `A2`.

Comment: Oh, I forget `pArmario * arrArmariosPointers`. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The type of the dynamic array variable is wrong. You're missing a pointer:

```
pArmario* arrArmariosPointers = malloc(sizeof(pArmario) * maxCorredores);
```

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
pArmario auxArmarioTest1
```

Is a pointer to a `struct recArmario`, this:

```
pArmario arrArmariosPointers
```

is the exact same thing. So if you dereference a pointer to a `struct` you'd have a `struct`.

Thus this code is:

```
*(arrArmariosPointers + idCorredor) = auxArmarioTest1;
^      ^                   ^                   ^
|      |                   |                   |
| array of pointers  +   some offset           |
|   to structs          into the array         |
|                                              |
dereference the result, so now we can          |
assign a struct                                |
                                        but here's a problem
                                       we're trying to give it a pointer
                                       to a struct.
```

So the answer to your question is yes:
`*(arrArmariosPointers + idCorredor)` is equivalent to `arrArmariosPointers[idCorredor]`

But what you really wanted was:

```
pArmario* arrArmariosPointers = malloc(sizeof(pArmario) * maxCorredores);
   ^    ^
   |    |
   |    +-- pointer to (array of)
   pointers to structs
```